# Domain Datasource not updating in Silverlight Project after Changing Entity

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, domainservices

I have a Silverlight project that is accessing data via a Domain Service/Entity Framwork. I made a change to the database, I then updated teh EDMX, and then deleted and recreated the Domain Service. I can see the newly added properties in the DomainServiceName.metadata.cs file.

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the data source to refresh in the Silverlight project. I have recompiled, deleted the DomainContext file and regenerated it, but the objects on the Silverlight side to not have the new properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a temp RIA project and used it to remake the Domain Service and just lifted the code that I needed. Not optimal but it saved me from having to manually type all of the metadata and service methods.